# Can I access Resources file from a View in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, file, resources

I want to populate dropdownlist with values stored in a resource file. What's the best approach for this?

I can create a SelectList and push it in Model in which case dropdown would be populated automatically. 
But can I access resource file from a View ? If yes, should I?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All resource strings get compiled into a class which you can reference in your views. Example:

```
<%= Resources.Strings.MyCustomString %>
```

I believe the following is automatically added to your web.config so you can drop the Resources..

```
<namespaces>
    <add namespace="Resources">
</namespaces>
```

However, this will not support localization. For that you'll want to use a [helper method](http://blog.eworldui.net/post/2008/05/ASPNET-MVC---Localization.aspx).

If you're trying to populate a list you'll need to create a helper class that can iterate through the Strings class and extract the appropriate values or encode your selections in a comma delimited list and parse/split that before feeding it to your dropdownlist's selectionlist.

Comment: Using VS2012 and an MVC 4 project, I had to manually add that namespace to my Web.config file; after that, and making sure my resource file Access Modifier was set to public, it worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tried this yet, but read somewhere that resources works the same way they worked in web forms.

Comment: I tried including namespace in View and then accessing it using Resources but its not working..

Answer (score 2):

Use the following:

```
<%= Resources.Strings.MyCustomString %>
```

I don't understand what Todd mean by "it doesn't support localization", it's exactly what it does.