# Resources files issues in ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, localization, globalization

I´m having a strange problem with resources files. Strange because it was working great.
Well, I have some resources files. I created a Resources folder on my asp.net mvc 3 project structure and I am mirroring the views's folder structure. For now I have:

```
Views
   Shared
      _Layout.cshtml

Resources
   Shared
      Layout.pt-BR.resx
      Layout.en-US.resx
      Layout.ko-KR.resx
```

All resources files are configured as Embedded Resource, PublicResXFileCodeGenerator and with Custom Tool Namespace "ViewRes". All ".Designer.cs" files are empty. I remember to see some code in them when it was working.

On my .csproj file I have these data:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="Resources\Shared\Layout.en-US.resx">
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
      <Generator>PublicResXFileCodeGenerator</Generator>
      <LastGenOutput>Layout.en-US.Designer.cs</LastGenOutput>
      <CustomToolNamespace>ViewRes</CustomToolNamespace>
    </EmbeddedResource>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="Resources\Shared\Layout.ko-KR.resx">
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
      <Generator>PublicResXFileCodeGenerator</Generator>
      <CustomToolNamespace>ViewRes</CustomToolNamespace>
      <LastGenOutput>Layout.ko-KR.Designer.cs</LastGenOutput>
    </EmbeddedResource>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="Resources\Shared\Layout.pt-BR.resx">
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
      <Generator>PublicResXFileCodeGenerator</Generator>
      <LastGenOutput>Layout.pt-BR.Designer.cs</LastGenOutput>
      <CustomToolNamespace>ViewRes</CustomToolNamespace>
    </EmbeddedResource>
  </ItemGroup>
```

The problem is: When I try to access the @ViewRes on my views, It is not recognized. I tried already to remove the custom tool namespace but the @Resource is not recognized too. In both situations I got this compilation error:

```
Compiler Error Message: CS0103: The name 'ViewRes' does not exist in the current context
```

Does anybody have any idea?
Thanks,
Paulo

EDIT: NEW INFORMATIONS

I created a global Resources.resx file by project's properties menu in VS2010 and it's working with the custom tool namespaces I have entered. "Resources" namespace still not working. I think the problem is with the local resources files. Unfortunatly I need them because I can't rename the global resources.resx file including the culture code.

EDIT 2
I created new .resx file on Resource folder and what I can see is that the filename can not have 2 ".". Is the name is Resources.resx, it works. If the name is Resource-en-US.resx, it works but, If the name is Resources.en-US.resx it fails!

Comment: I think it might help you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/886473/can-i-access-resources-file-from-a-view-in-mvc

Comment: I've noticed that you should add one resource file without two dots for the namespace to get created

Answer (score 0):

I think you can also write a custom helper, that will return by reflection the string.

Comment: Yes, I can try it but does it make sense? It´s the default resources's naming convention: xxx.yy-zz.resx.